# Can all functions/mappings be written as a recursive formula?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

Background:

In math class, the teacher was explaining recursion with examples like the Fibonacci sequence and the gamma function and proved how both examples can be written recursively. He taught us that a recursive formula is isomorphic to a map from $T \rightarrow U$, and a function is isomorphic to a map from $U \rightarrow T$ and the representation of such formulas can be written in lambda calculus. We only have studied functions with subsets of N as the domain

Question:

Can you turn all functions into a recursive formula?

Instinctively I thought not, but I was wondering if someone could provide any insight.

Comment: Can you please clarify some notation? What are $U$ and $T$? And what functions do you want? Functions from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; consider all functions from $\mathbb{N} $ to $ \{0, 1\} $. By Cantor's famous [diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument), there is an uncountable number of such functions